# Node.js fs.unlink function causes EPERM error

Tags: node.js

I'm using `fs.unlink()` to delete a file and I receive the following error:

```
uncaught undefined: 

Error: EPERM, Operation not permitted '/Path/To/File'
```

Anyone know a why this is happening?

Comment: Check your error message ?! Try to do the same with the user who run the process. (i.e: /> unlink /path/To/file )

Answer (score 48):

You cannot delete a directory that is not empty.
And fs.unlinkSync() is used to delete a file not a folder.

To remove an empty folder, use
fs.rmdir()

to delete a non empty folder, use this snippet:

```
var deleteFolderRecursive = function(path) {
  if( fs.existsSync(path) ) {
      fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file) {
        var curPath = path + "/" + file;
          if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
              deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
          } else { // delete file
              fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
          }
      });
      fs.rmdirSync(path);
    }
};
```

Snippet from stackoverflow: [Is node.js rmdir recursive ? Will it work on non empty directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627586/is-node-js-rmdir-recursive-will-it-work-on-non-empty-directories/12761924#12761924)

Comment: Got the same error by updating a npm module while the app was using it! Thanks.

Comment: This snippet should NOT be used in any code that handles client request since it performs synchronous IO and will lock your entire application while deleting a potentially large directory tree.

Comment: @lnwdr Yes this snippet is bad for large directories in a client request. But this is okay to use for relatively small directory tree. Can you provide any workaround for deleting a directory tree that's coming from a client request? That will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Even with small directory trees this can grind your application to a halt pretty quickly, especially if there may be high latency over a network share for example. Only ever use the Async versions of IO functions in request handling code. I've pulled this from a recent project of mine: https://gist.github.com/lnwdr/38dd505f49e60bc291af It uses promises to help manage all the concurrent operations and is entirely non-blocking.

Comment: Infortunately I don't think this answer (somehow usefull), aswer the problem of @Mark Gia Bao Nguyen

Comment: He is saying /path/to/file

file being a file not a directory

Comment: What is the reason for that? In the OS you can also delete a non-empty folder?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to achieve something like rm -rf does, there is a package from npm called [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rimraf) which makes it very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the **Path** of the file is located is erroneus.

if not, try with **fs.unlinkSync()**

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you don't have permission to delete/unlink that file. Try again with more rights or verify that you're giving it the right path.