# How to delete compiled JS files from previous typescript(.ts) files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, angular

I am following [Angular 2 quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) tutorial. Following is my folder structure -

```
├── gulpfile.js
├── index.html
├── js
|   ├── app.component.js
|   └── boot.js
├── source
|   ├── app.component.ts
|   └── boot.ts
├── node_modules
    ├── module 1
    └── module 2
```

My typescript files are in `source/` directory. I'm compiling it to `js/` directory. I'm using gulp-typescript.

The problem is when I, for example, rename the file `boot.ts` to `bootstrap.ts` and compile again, corresponding `bootstrap.js` file is created but the old `boot.js` file still remains in the js/ directory.

Now the folder structure looks like following-

```
├── gulpfile.js
├── index.html
├── js
|   ├── app.component.js
|   └── bootstrap.js
|   └── boot.js
├── source
|   ├── app.component.ts
|   └── bootstrap.ts
├── node_modules
    ├── module 1
    └── module 2
```

I want to delete this `boot.js` autonomically via gulp task. How to achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I came here seeing the title, and adding gulp into the mix was not a solution. So here is how I solved it.

Prefix your npm build script with `rm -rf ./js/ &&`

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "rm -rf ./js/ && tsc",
    ...
},
```

`rm -rf ./js/` **f**orcefully removes **r**ecursively all files and dirs below ./js/ [doku rm in bash](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rm/)

`&&` says, if successful do the next command [&& in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)

> Title at the time of answering:
> **"How to delete compiled JS files from previous typescript(.ts) files?"**

Comment: If you are using a windows dev environment, you can also use `rm` if you add `cash-rm` as a dev dependency. Similarly, you can use `rimraf` (aptly named for `rm -rf`) instead if saved as a dev dependency.

Comment: @samthecodingman For the record, I am a Windows developer by choice :) I have tried Mac and Linux, I really don't feel at home on either of them. I just don't like them, even MacOS. Everything is smooth (for me, at least) in Windows, no matter how bad most developers seem to hate it.

Comment: `rimraf` is for windows machine.  ```"prebuild":"rimraf dist",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.release.json",```

Comment: Works also for server-side projects and projects that are not using gulp.

Answer (score 93):

with the latest tsc, you should be fine to do the clean with below command

```
tsc --build --clean
```

My current tsc version for your reference

```
$ tsc --version
Version 3.5.3
```

Note that --clean flag is part of [project-references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) and works only with it.

Comment: Nope, does not work. At least not for me. `tsc --version: Version 3.5.3` and `tsc --build --clean` does not do what is asked.

Comment: i did it as daily task, not sure why it doesn't work in your environment, any details for your issue?

Comment: cannot see that "--clean" is part of the compiler options. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Seems it is hide option? did you try with it in your environment?

Comment: @Elias  --clean flag is part of project-references and works only with it.

Comment: --clean doesn't clean all outDir (deleted TS files remain compiled in outDir, but not cleaned...)

Comment: This is not correct, --clean will not remove the transpiled files from a previous run it will remove any files generated as part of this transpile according to its documentation.

Answer (score 24):

This solution is inspired in [@Akash Kurian Jose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838151/2561119). Since his solution depends on the OS you're using, I'm adding this one which will work on any OS:

Add [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) as a dev dependency:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "rimraf": "^3.0.1"
}
```

Then add these 3 scripts to your package.json:

```
"rimraf": "./node_modules/rimraf/bin.js",
"clean" : "rimraf js/",
"compile": "npm run clean && tsc -p ./"
```

When executing `npm run compile` the `js/` folder will be cleaned before compiling.

Comment: I've always wondered, why add another package `rimraf` when `rm -rf` is a faster native alternative present literally everywhere?

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon because it doesn’t work when using Windows

Comment: Even if you have Cygwin, for some reason `rimrar node_modules` is faster than `rm -rf .\node_modules` according to my tests.

Answer (score 9):

Install gulp del.

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp del
```

Create the task.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean:output', function () {
  return del([
    'js/'
  ]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean:output']);
```

You can find more info on gulp del [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md).

Comment: This seems to be MUCH more complicated than https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838151/4693430. Why do you recommend this anyway?

Comment: because at the time I didn't know better. I agree that the other solution is a lot simpler and better. It's up to the OP to change the accepted answer to that one. I hope he does. :)

Answer (score 9):

This solution is an improvement on [GabrielBB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59997613/737997) solution.

Install rimraf
`npm i rimraf -D`

Add the following npm scripts

```
"clean": "rimraf js/",
"prebuild": "npm run clean",
"build": "tsc",
```

This makes use of npms automatic [Pre scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts)

Comment: Upvote for clear answer, but also for enlightening me about pre scripts - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just if someone will come across this question:
I was trying to use `tsc --build --clean`
but sometimes if you renamed a lot of .ts files this command is working on mac:

to delete .js files if you renamed a lot of .ts (this is for Mac users):

`find . -name '*.js' ! -path './node_modules/*' -delete`

if `declaration: true` in your tsconfig file you may want to:

`find . -name '*.d.ts' ! -path './node_modules/*' -delete`

don't forget to `git commit` before deleting files

Answer (score 2):

Windows users can add the following **prebuild** script on `package.json` - a batch cmd script - which will run automatically before **build** command, just as [@Llewellyn Collins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128892/14549262) stated:

###### `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "if exist <outDir> (rmdir /Q /S <outDir>)",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
}
```

Replace "`<outDir>`" with the actual `outDir` declared in your `tsconfig.json`.

If you omit the `if exist` command, it will throw an error.

It should run correctly even if your main terminal application is PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

I use script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197381/10188661).

In package.json add script:

```
"build": "node jsDelete.js && npx tsc -w"
```

And add jsDelete.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');

const deleteFolderRecursive = function(path) {
  if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach((file, index) => {
      const curPath = Path.join(path, file);
      if (fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
      }
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(path);
  }
};

deleteFolderRecursive('path_to_folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hack using Git and Bash

```
git add . && git stash &&  find . \\( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.js.map' \\) ! -path './node_modules/*' -delete  && git restore . && git stash pop
```

Comment: DO NOT RUN THIS. This command deleted all my files

Answer (score 0):

simple move to ur src file and the run the remove file with this pattern

```html
cd src
rm -rf */**/*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For that folks who accidentally run just `tsc` for new package (with e.g. copied files) and want to remove all the `.js` and `.d.ts` files recursively:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.d.ts" \) -print -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It should do the job.