# TypeScript Watch - Removing Deleted Target JS Files

Tags: typescript, gulp, tsconfig, file-watcher

Microsoft [fixed an issue with Typescript still generating JS compiled output in TS 2.0 even though the source file was deleted](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3780/files). What the solution involved was using file watchers to trigger deletion callback event and removing the `tsc watch` file from the source file list.

Is there a reason we can't also delete the target output files when a source file is deleted? This creates issues when you are refactoring as functions / JS types collide and create crashes.

Wouldn't it seem trivial to [add a tsconfig compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to also delete targets (`.js.map`, `.js`) so that `tsc -watch` will not require user to continuously stop/start or [use gulp to clean the output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567043/175679)? You could easily use a glob pattern to identify target outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> You could easily use a glob pattern to identify target outputs

You can. But its easier to simply use `outDir` and blow away at the `outDir` to clear old files.

Comment: this approach requires manual intervention, when refactoring current branch or switching branches for collaboration this could be automated to reduce the manual `gulp clean` step. Just curious if we can bring this change forward with the `tsc` tooling.

Comment: `tsc -w` was never intended to accomodate all use cases. You mostly use `webpack -w` or `watchify` or gulp or whatever else strikes your fancy and TSC will work with that seamlessly 