# Can fs.unlink() delete a empty or non empty folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am new to Node.js.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.unlink('/tmp/hello', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
});
```

This is some code that I copied from a node.js document file system intro example.

But, I am confused. Can `unlink()` delete a folder or not?

I have tried but it doesn't work.

So, can `unlink()` delete a folder or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The [fs.unlink(path, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) function is used to delete a file not a folder.

To remove a folder you can use the [fs.rmdir(path, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_callback) function instead.

Comment: If I unlink the file then, of course, it will be deleted from targeted folder

Comment: You can also see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052762/remove-directory-which-is-not-empty by SharpCoder answer

Comment: I would look at [the documentation you linked](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html).

Comment: It also says same `unlink() deletes a name from the filesystem.  If that name was the
       last link to a file and no processes have the file open, the file is
       deleted and the space it was using is made available for reuse.` my word is just defference

Comment: And this leads us to my first comment. Loop closed.

Comment: @skypjack is this a case of being nitpicky or trying to confuse people? can you be more specific what unlink does if not deleting files ? your comments seem like cheap trolling.