# Deleting the contents of folder with rm -r folder_name/* in npm script gives 'no such folder or directory' error

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

When I try to clean a folder with npm by running `npm run clean` (code underneath), I get the following error:

> rm: cannot remove 'lib/*': No such file or directory

In my package.json, I'm using the following scripts:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rm -r lib/*",
        "show": "ls lib/*"
    }
}
```

I'm absolutely sure the folder exists. I've tried using single quotes around the `lib` path. I know glob expansion is working: the `npm run show` works perfectly fine.

I do not want to add any dependencies like rimraf as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682848/how-to-clean-delete-contents-folder-with-npm). I also do not care about windows support. I know I could use `rm -r lib && mkdir lib` which does work. I'm mostly interested in why `rm -r lib/*` gives the error. Could someone help me out?

**npm version:** 5.5.1

**node version:** 8.9.3

Comment: Maybe script runs in another directory, then the folder exists? Try to `pwd` to print path from script run

Comment: I've actually thought about that, but then why would the `npm run show` command work? To be sure I just tested it with `pwd` in a npm script and it returns the correct folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure your lib folder is not already empty?

```
rm -r somedir/*
```

Gives this error when ran on an empty dir because "*" doesn't exist because the dir is empty.

If you want to remove the lib folder itself you have to type `rm -r lib`

Comment: There is mentioned he knows about that he can remove whole folder and recreate `I know I could use rm -r lib && mkdir lib which does work` but I guess he wants to know why its failing. 
Good point.

Comment: Oh wow. Was pretty sure I've tried that, but I'm wrong. Thank you! Guess I have to do a check first before I delete the folder.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx: somehow I forgot one of the very basic things to check. Thank you both for thinking along :)

Answer (score 5):

Use rimraf: **Run the unix command rm -rf in Node.js**

```
npm i rimraf -D
```

and in your script, write

```
"scripts": {
    "delete:folder": "rimraf lib/*",
}
```