# Is there any way to exclude a folder while building (ng build), which is present in assets folder in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 9 app. developing front end from mock-content. the software will be embedded to hardware. I have placed mock-content folder under assets folder. my problem is when building (ng build --prod) the mock-content folder is also present in the assets folder. i need to delete the mock content every time in order to embed(update) the software in the hardware.

Comment: what's make you stop delete the folder after the ng build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682848/how-to-clean-delete-contents-folder-with-npm

Comment: i dont want to update/embed the mock-content in the hardware, hardware as the server side scripting. mock-content has built using the same server response  in a node.js file to start the front end development