# How to delete a directory using CasperJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, phantomcss

I'm trying to delete a dir recursively which contains files. However, I'm getting error message although the directory exists:

> uncaughtError: Unable to remove directory './screenshots/build'

`fs.removeDirectory('./screenshots/build');`

Comment: This is already in discussion -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052762/remove-directory-which-is-not-empty