# how to delete file using FileSystem in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, multiparty

I dont know why ,but i am not able to delete file using `unlink()` and `unlinksynk()`.

I have stored file using `multiparty.Form()` method. It will generate file with random name and returns `filePath` and `originalFileName`. And after this i have renamed file with `originalFileName`.

Code:

```
      await form.parse(fileData, (err: Error, fields: any, res: any) => {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        } else {
          let file_path = res.file[0].path;
          let assignedFilePath = file_path.substr(res.file[0].path.lastIndexOf('\/') + 1);
          let originalFilePath = res.file[0].originalFilename;
          originalFilePath = path.dirname(assignedFilePath) + '\\' + originalFilePath;
          fs.rename(assignedFilePath, originalFilePath, function (err: any) {
            if (err)
              callback(err, null);
            else
              callback(err, JSON.stringify({'path': originalFilePath}));
          });
        }
      });
```

Code for deleteFile()

```
 deleteTempFiles(tempFolderPath: string) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve: any, reject: any) {
      fs.readdir(tempFolderPath, (err: any, files: any) => {
        if (err) {
          reject();
        } else {
          for (let file of files) {
            fs.unlink(tempFolderPath + file, (err: any) => {
              if (err) {
                reject();
              }
            });
          }
          resolve();
        }
      });
    }).catch(function (e) {
      Promise.reject(e.message);
    })
  }
```

EDIT :

ERROR is, while deleting file ,compiler says `Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink`.

And I think i am not using the file anywhere in program ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your code example doesn't contain a delete call - did you forget to add it?

An unrelated advice, use `path.join(...parts)` to construct paths, and use `path.separator` instead of the `'\\'` here.

Comment: hi Zlatko ,of-course i have added delete call but in other function. This is my generic method to add any type of file on server. but i think the root cause is getting from this code only  ;)

Comment: for delete purpose i have used FileSystem (fs) to perform operations on file. ```unlink(filePath)``` for delete file. and thanks for advice, i will do it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==== 2nd answer ===

Your `deleteTempFiles` function is utterly wrong
read this [removing of each file in directory (and directories) inside a dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41052903/3535045)

You have many logical errors in the code.

1. You use a synchronius for loop, to queue tasks of removing list of files (And directories) from given directory.
2. You unlinks all - even directories `.` and `..` - not possible
3. You ALWAYS `resolve`s after that loop, and rejects after 1st error - but usually that reject should be much after resolve (loop is fast, it only queues io access, not executing the unlinks yet, then resolve is executed).

==== 1st answer ===

You have code for `renameFile`, which moves file form old name(and location) into new one. Therefore deleting old file would not work at all so you should delete new file.

Comment: hi Seti, it seems like, i am storing new file in other location, but actually i am changing it in same folder .only file name's are changed from both input path's.

Comment: then you need to remove the ,,new'' file

Comment: yes i am doing that but getting one error , i have updated question just now :)

Comment: add the code for removal +execution of that code to the question

Comment: Resource busy etc, means that some process can still have the file opened (for example node itself).

Comment: Also i see some errors in your code: for example your removable code :
 1. read all files (also file .. and .) in directory, Also read all directories.
 2.  in loop - set all of them to be unlinked.
 3.  when loop finishes - `resolve`
 how you even get the reject i dont know...

Comment: yep, i have updated my code as you mentioned and also i found location, where exactly my file is locked(used) using debugger . Issue is solved now . Thank you for help :)

Comment: Glad i could help! - can you mark the question as answered (you can answer on it yourself with the answer)