# Unable to delete directory using node.js

Tags: node.js, directory, fs

I am trying to delete directory using `fs` module from node.js but as per my current code its throwing the following error.

**Error:**

```
Error:: { Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/app/uploads'
at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:684:3)
at Object.usecaseWorkflow (/app/controller/usecaseWorkflowCtrl.js:97:32)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
errno: -39,
syscall: 'rmdir',
code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
path: '/app/uploads' }
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
if (fs.existsSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads`)) {
    fs.rmdirSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads`, { 
          recursive: true, 
    });
}
```

Here I am trying to delete `uploads` directory present inside root directory but getting that error and also unable to delete. I am using `node.js version 10`.  Can anybody help me to resolve this issue so that I can delete the directory successfully ?

Comment: `recursive` option was added in Node.js v12.1 See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052762/remove-directory-which-is-not-empty

Comment: yes true. I am trying different approach now.

Answer (score 2):

Just use node.js `rimraf` to delete files recursively.

```
var rimraf = require("rimraf");
rimraf("/some/directory", function () { console.log("done"); });
```