# Error removing directory which is not empty

Tags: node.js, cypress, rmdir

I'm trying to delete a directory when all the tests finish with an after, and I get the following error:

```
fs.rmdir is not a function
```

Here is mi code:

```
after(() => {
        const fs = require('fs');
        const dir = '../../../../../../downloads';
        
        fs.rmdir(dir, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the [`recursive` option is deprecated from Node.js 14.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866165/10401931) (what version do you use?), so you can now use:

```js
fs.rm(dir, { recursive: true, force: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @pavelsaman im using 14.18.1

Comment: Seems like a later version. `fs.rm()` works, or not?

Comment: no, not works :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `fs` is a Node library, but you are trying to use it in the browser.

For Node code, use a task

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
const fs = require('f')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    clearDownloads(message) {
      const fs = require('fs');
      const dir = '../../../../../../downloads';
        
      fs.rm(dir, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      });
      return null
    },
  })
}
```

But there's a couple of configuration items that seem to do this job for you

Ref [Configuration - Downloads](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Downloads)

> **downloadsFolder** - Path to folder where files downloaded during a test are saved
>
> **trashAssetsBeforeRuns** - Whether Cypress will trash assets within the downloadsFolder, screenshotsFolder, and videosFolder before tests run with cypress run.

Comment: Hi, thank for your response but now i got this error: `cy.clearDownloads is not a function` with this: `after(() => {
        cy.clearDownloads()
    })`

Comment: Ok, you call a task with `cy.task('clearDownloads')` - see [this page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task)