# How to remove a directory if it exists and is not empty?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to remove node_modules directory if it exists and is not empty

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    child_process = require('child_process'),
    cmd;

module.exports = function(){
    var modulesPath = '../modules';

    fs.readdirSync(modulesPath)
        .forEach(function(dir) {
            var location = path.join(dir, 'node_modules');
            if (fs.existsSync(location)){
                fs.rmdir(location);
            }
        });
};
```

However, `fs.rmdir` command unfortunately removes directory *only if there are no files there*.

NodeJS doesn’t have an easy way to force the removal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of things:

where does your next(err) function come from?

Also remember that rmdir in node.js documentation for the function you are calling is this:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmdir_path_callback

```
Asynchronous rmdir(2)
```

The posix definition of this is:

```
deletes a directory, which must be empty.
```

Make sure your directory is **empty**, which in this case it seems it would not be.

There is a gist here the deals with non-empty directories:

https://gist.github.com/tkihira/2367067

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

var rmdir = function(dir) {
    var list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var filename = path.join(dir, list[i]);
        var stat = fs.statSync(filename);

        if(filename == "." || filename == "..") {
            // pass these files
        } else if(stat.isDirectory()) {
            // rmdir recursively
            rmdir(filename);
        } else {
            // rm fiilename
            fs.unlinkSync(filename);
        }
    }
    fs.rmdirSync(dir);
};
```

And a node module here:

https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.rmdir

These might get you on the right track.

Comment: thanks! Very helpful:) find also [thread with asynchronous method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627586/is-node-js-rmdir-recursive-will-it-work-on-non-empty-directories/12761924#12761924)

Answer (score 9):

Two Liner:

```js
if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.rmdirSync(dir, {recursive: true})
}
```

Comment: Both of the functions you used are synchronous (hence Sync). The async variants can be imported from the "fs/promises" built in, although exists has been depreciated. existsSync is active but again isn't a promise. Hope this helps!

Comment: One liner: `fs.rmSync('./dir', {force: true, recursive: true});`. [Source](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rmsync_path_options)

Answer (score 5):

### Update v16 - Async & Recursive Method

You can now use [`fs.rm()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmpath-options-callback) or [`fs.promises.rm()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrmpath-options) like this:

```js
fs.rm("/directory-to-delete", { recursive: true, force: true })
```

**Options**:

- `recursive <boolean>` If true, perform a recursive directory removal.
- `force <boolean>` If true, exceptions will be ignored if path does not exist.

#### Further Reading

- [Remove directory which is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052762/1366033)
- [rmdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrmdirpath-options) v16.0.0 - The `recursive` option is deprecated, using it triggers a deprecation warning.

Comment: As it's now 2023 this should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var child_process = require('child_process');
var cmd;

module.exports = function(){
    var modulesPath = 'modules';

    fs.readdirSync(modulesPath)
        .forEach(function(dir) {
            var location = path.join(dir, 'node_modules');
            if (fs.existsSync(location)){
                fs.rmdir(location, function (err) {
                    return next(err);
                })
            }
        });
};
```

make sure check modules folder in current path.

Comment: What is `next` in this case?

Comment: I know this answer is a bit old, but i submitted an edit request as i think this code is supposed to be a middleware (And this is why the `next` keyword). Next is probably supposed to be from `(req, res, next)` (parameters). It would be nice if the answer has some description around it.

Answer (score 0):

@since 14.4.0

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// note `fm.rm` and `fm.rmSync` can delete files and directories
// retry options not required - might be needed if an EBUSY, EMFILE, ENFILE, ENOTEMPTY, or EPERM error is encountered
// the `force` option When true, exceptions will be ignored if path does not exist.
// the `recursive` If true, perform a recursive directory removal. In recursive mode, operations are retried on failure.

// async version - prefered - you may need to await the file deletion - works like `rm -rf`
fs.promises.rm(`<FILE|DIR_PATH>`, { maxRetries: 5, retryDelay: 2000, recursive: true, force: true })

// sync version - works like `rm -rf`
fs.rmSync(`<FILE|DIR_PATH>`, { maxRetries: 5, retryDelay: 2000, recursive: true, force: true })
```

Refer To:

- async - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrmpath-options
- sync - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmsyncpath-options