# file operation permission - nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems

In file operations with [wrench](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/wrench-js/) by [`copyDirSyncRecursive`](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/wrench-js/blob/master/lib/wrench.js#L166) (with `opts: { preserve: false }`), I get the `Error: EPERM, operation not permitted` error.

[As I pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496212/node-js-fs-unlink-function-causes-eperm-error), is this a permission violation in filesystem?
If it is, is there a way to authenticate me as `admin / root` to execute this operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 comments:

- Don't use synchronous operations. Node.js it's asynchronous by nature. If you want to write synchronous code use another scripting language like python. If you use a single synchronous function you're blocking the entire event loop and the rest of asynchronous functions will need to wait.
- Don't use wrench.js. It's bugged and has a bad error management especially in the parallel asynchronous functions (readdirRecursive, rmdirRecursive, etc). I can't understand how a bugged code that can ruin you're entire application has 150+ stars.
- Don't use wrench.js. It promotes a bad usage of node.js using synchronous functions.
- If you want to execute forbidden operation start node.js with admin privileges (windows) or root permissions (linux).

Comment: In software development, you should never say never - Unless you have considered every possibility! For example Wrench is perfectly acceptable for making a cli script using Node.js (which I think is what it was intended for). On a side node - I am tired of hearing people saying to NEVER use Sync functions; if you are using the cluster module; it may actually be a suitable option if you're not blocking the other threads which handle the requests - The most important rule in programming is to think ahead.